# How to make a label like popup dialog from navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, dialog, popup

I found a good pop up dialog to show some message.
User don't need to click anything.

Does someone know how to make a label like popup dialog from navigation bar as follows:

Normal(Nothing but just for compare...):

[image: The normal screen before show:(just for compare...)]

Then dialog appeared:
[image: The dialog appears after I click something:]

Answer (score 0):

You can add target to that close button and in that targeted method you can dismiss your popup dialogue.

If you want to dismiss this popup window after some time you can use following code block.

Here I am performing action after 2 seconds.

```
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //dismiss popup window
    });
```

**Edited**

For that type of popup dialog you can use below library.

https://github.com/edgurgel/CMNavBarNotificationView

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. But what  I want to know is how to make UI parts like that...
I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ok. You want notification popup in above or place of navigation bar when any notification comes?  This library might help you       https://github.com/edgurgel/CMNavBarNotificationView

Comment: Thank you. It seems very well